# Dimension too large when typesetting large proof tree

Tags: pdftex

I'm trying to typeset a very large (generated) proof tree. The source looks something like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{prftree}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\resizebox{1.0\textwidth}{!}{%
(...prftree...)
%
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

And then the error:

```
./proof.tex:415: Dimension too large.
```

Is there some way I can do this anyway? I'm fine with either a proof tree with tiny text on an A4, or normal text on a huge page; I intend to zoom in on it anyway :)

I've tried:

```
\setlength\maxdimen{10000cm}
```

but from what I understand now it's a fixed constant.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments, or with dummy text as `(...prftree...)`. Instead, provide a complete compilable  document that let us *reproduce* the problem.

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin Sure! How should I attach it? It's about 400 lines, and due to the nature of the error I don't think I can minimize it much...

Comment: edit the question and use code markup. the process of creating a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) should also help you to find where the problem is